# WAMP server not reading included PHP file

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a web site that I am working on, it is fairly simple but it uses a MySQL database. I did initial development of this site in Linux using Apache 2.2.25, PHP 5.4.17, and MySQL 5.1. Everything worked fine on this server stack. However, I am having an incredibly strange error on Windows, using the latest WAMP server. There are a number of files involved in this site, but as far as the index page goes, there is a basic layout of includes:

```
index.php
->header.php
--->connection.php
--->functions.php
->footer.php
```

When I load the index page, the header is definitely being included properly, as is the functions.php, which contains all the site and database functions, including the function to open a SQL connection using mysqli. However, the connection.php, which contains defines for the server information, does not seem to get read at all when the page is loaded. I get errors such as

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in D:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 2",

even though these are definitely defined in connection.php, and connection.php is included first. I have also tried reorganizing the includes so they go like this:

```
index.php
->header.php
--->functions.php
----->connection.php
```

That also did not change the problem. I even tried adding a die() and a mail() into the connection.php for testing purposes. Nothing in that file is getting executed. I would like to repeat that this exact code and file layout worked just fine on the LAMP stack. I have no idea why this is happening, as there doesn't seem to be a reason for it.

Edit: This should have been in my original post. The code for my defines (in connection.php) is as follows:

```
define("DB_NAME", "lyricsdb");
define("DB_USER", "lyricsdb");
define("DB_PASS", "XXXXXXXXX");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
```

And these constants are referenced in the following function in functions.php:

```
function sql_connect($db_host = DB_HOST, $db_user = DB_USER, $db_pass = DB_PASS, $db_name = DB_NAME) {
    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die('Could not connect to database.');
    return $con;
}
```

Edit 2: It works fine if I move my defines into the top of the functions.php file. What is this I don't even?

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that your file is being included, but you will always get warnings about undefined constant if you reference array keys like this

`$db[DB_HOST];`

They should be referenced as

`$db['DB_HOST']`

If you are sure your variable is defined, then check you have included the ''s around the variable name so it looks for a key name rather than looking for something that has been defined as a constant. This is just warning you that if there was a  `define('DB_HOST','something');` then that would take precedence over your `$db['DB_HOST']` and it would instead look for `$db['something']`

Comment: I forgot to include this in my original post (I meant to) but the way my constants are defined is as such:

`define("DB_NAME", "lyricsdb");
define("DB_USER", "lyricsdb");
define("DB_PASS", "XXXXXXXXXX");
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");`

And referenced as such:

`function sql_connect($db_host = DB_HOST, $db_user = DB_USER, $db_pass = DB_PASS, $db_name = DB_NAME) {
 $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die('Could not connect to database.');
 return $con;
}`

Comment: Can you update your question to include that information please along with which file each bit is in